# Maximum length for longtext field

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a database driven website for a Chinese audience in PHP. The content is stored in the database as a `longtext` field.

I was wondering how can I be sure the data to be stored isn't truncated?

Comment: I really would hope that people would not enter 4GB worth of data via a textarea in an HTML form.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It depends on the characters' sizes and some configuration options.

> LONGTEXT [CHARACTER SET charset_name]
>   [COLLATE collation_name]
>
> A TEXT column with a maximum length of
>   4,294,967,295 or 4GB (2^32 – 1)
>   characters. The effective maximum
>   length is less if the value contains
>   multi-byte characters. The effective
>   maximum length of LONGTEXT columns
>   also depends on the configured maximum
>   packet size in the client/server
>   protocol and available memory. Each
>   LONGTEXT value is stored using a
>   four-byte length prefix that indicates
>   the number of bytes in the value.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html

Comment: Could you explain why it also depends on the maximum packet size?

Comment: I think because it might get cut off if you try to send something that exceeds the maximum packet size, though it would fit in longtext